# Multicast communication betwen two subnets connected to one switch

Tags: multicast

Computers A and and B are connected to the same switch. A is in subnet 192.168.1.0/24, B in 192.168.2.0/24, so they cannot communicate directly using unicast. But what about multicast communication? Will it work or not?

There are no other devices or software here which could help with packet routing.

Comment: just to fully understand, why both computers are configured in 2 different subnets, if they are supposed to be able to communicate, and there is no routing solution ?

Comment: @ChaoxiangN: They should not communicate together. I have concerns that both computers may try to use the same multicast address for their own purposes, and may inadvertently disrupt each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If A and B are in the same VLAN on that switch then both multicast and certain types of broadcast will be seen by both.